Difference between right singular element of a ring and right zero divisor of a ring?
Let $R$ be a ring. An element $a$ of $R$ is said to be right zero divisor if there exists non-zero element $b\in R$ such that $ba=0$.
An element $a\in R$ is called right singular element of $R$ if $ann_r(a)=\lbrace b\in R~|~ab=0\rbrace$ is an essential right ideal of $R$.
Note: A right ideal $I$ of $R$ is called essential if $I\cap I'\ne 0$ for any non-zero right ideal $I'$ of $R$.
My attempt: Let $x$ be a right zero divisor of $R$. Then there exists $(y\ne 0)\in R$ such that $yx=0$. Now, since we do not that the annihilator of $x$ contains just $y$ or something else, we cannot say it forms an essential ideal. So my question is: Is there any relation between them, it seems like right zero divisor maybe a left singular element?
